# Style or CSS won't work

Tags: html, css

Here's my `input` from a `modal form`

```
<input class="input-medium pull-left atcCode" type="text" id="atcCode" style="text-transform : none">
```

When I type on the `input`, it is all `capitalized`. And when I `inspect element` the code, `style="text-transform : none"` is gone.

```
<input class="input-medium pull-left atcCode" type="text" id="atcCode">
```

I also tried in `CSS` but also won't work.

```
.atcCode{
    text-transform: none;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Inspect the input element and look for the style that is setting it to uppercase. If there isn't one, or it's inline, it could be that a piece of javascript is setting as uppercase. Also make sure you're not getting a cached version of your page.

Answer (score 1):

Try using '!important' like this:

```
.atcCode{
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

Then, hit Ctrl+F5 to refresh your css.

If it doesn't work try using Ctrl+F and search for the word capitalized or text-transform in both your css and the page itself, see if it's somewhere in your css that is giving the capitalization effect. Try remove the whole class in your input tag and see if it is still capitalized. If it doesn't, then the problem lie in the two other classes and you can check the two classes specifically to see where is / are the capitalization attribute in there.

Also search for #input to see if the input tag is being given an attribute to have its text all capitalized. Some outer tags that are surrounding your input tag might be causing this as well.

Comment: If you remove the whole class, will it work? If it does, then we can narrow down to possibly the input-medium and pull-left are causing this.

Comment: It's also possible that some outer tags that are surrounding your input tag is giving it an effect as well.

Answer (score 0):

<s>In your css the mistake is to use .atcCode instead of #atcCode

The point is for classes, hashtag is for id.</s>

`text-trasform:none`
is the default value

use instead
`text-transform:lowercase`

Comment: .atcCode is not a mistake. class = "atcCode". You use ( . ) when calling a class.

Comment: You are right, i missed the class atcCode in your class lists :)